# Passing different type of props to component and be able to map them

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the component that received 2 different kind of types for the same prop.
Property for compoenent `DisplayFiles`

How can I inform component up front that I am passing this kind of Props or the `files` prop will specific kind of type?

Maybe there is other patter or way around to do it?

```
  isAws: boolean;
  files: (AwsValue | NormalFile)[];
}

AwsValue:

interface AwsValue {
  bucket: string;
  fileName: string;
  folderPath: string;
  lastModified: Date;
}

NormalFile:

export interface NormalFile {
  created: Date;
  fileName: string;
  folderId: number;
  instance: string;
  modified: Date;
}

export const DisplayFiles: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  isMetadataStep,
  files,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
              {files.map((file: AwsValue | NormalFile) => { /* here I want tried some like isAws ? AwsValue : NormalFile, but obiously it's doesn't work */
            return (
              <FileItem
                key={file.fileName}
                title={file.fileName}
                date={file.lastModified} /* here sometimes is lastModified if AwsValue  or modified if NormalFile type */
                isSelectable={isMetadataStep}
                isSelected={selectedFile=== file.fileName}
              />
            );
          })}
    </div>
  );
};

And maybe there is possibility to pass type of property `files` in the moment of init component

Parent Component:

export const ParentOfDisplayFiles: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <FileManager isMetadataStep={false} files={filteredFiles} /> {/* passed filteredFiles sometimes are AwsValues type or NormalFile */}
    </div>
  );
};`
```

Comment: Have you tried to introduce a union type? Like make type `File = AwsValue | NormalFile` and use `file: File` within files.map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Union type will allow you to do so. You have two choices in this case:

1. Keep the interfaces like that, adding a type Union like:

```
type File = AwsValue | NormalFile
```

Then add a function with a type guard in order to discriminate:

```
function isAwsValue(file: File): file is AwsValue {
   return file.hasOwnProperty('bucket'); // Or whatever control you would like to do at runtime
}
```

2. Use a *discriminated* union, adding a `type` (or whatever name you like) property to each interface, still adding a `File` union type:

```
interface AwsValue {
  type: 'aws',
  // ...
}

interface NormalFile {
  type: 'normal',
  // ...
}

type File = AwsValue | NormalFile
```

Then you can just check in your code the `type`:

```
let file: File = /* ... */;
if (file.type === 'aws') {
  // file.bucket, etc. Now TS will suggest you props assuming `file` is an `AwsValue`
}
```

Comment: The first one solution with guard type works! Perfect solution! Thank you so much :)